# QueryDSL dependency got error to achieve the goal 'process"

Tags: querydsl

I added the dependency and plugin in my pom.xml as [here](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa).

But the error is .

```
Execution default of goal com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process failed: 
Plugin com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to collect dependencies for com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.3 () 
(com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason by myself.

First, I should have added the prorerty of querydsl version and I added the library by manually because of firewall.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <systemPath>${system.score.path}/apt-maven-plugin-1.1.3.jar</systemPath>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    <systemPath>${system.score.path}/querydsl-apt-3.4.3.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Second, I added the vm option in eclipse.ini file.

```
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath
```

It works!!